# Non-negativity constraint in Newton's method

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, numerical-methods, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I am trying to understand how to use a Newton type method to minimise a nonlinear function $f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, subject to $Ax=b$ and $x \geq 0$. Here $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$, $b\in\mathbb{R}^{m}$ and $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$.

I enforce the equality constraint using the following Newton step:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\nabla^{2}f(x) && A^{T} \\
A && 0
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
\Delta x \\
\Delta y 
\end{pmatrix} = - 
\begin{pmatrix}
\nabla f(x)+ A^{T}y \\
Ax - b
\end{pmatrix}.
$$ The primal and dual variables are then updated by $x \leftarrow x + \alpha\Delta x$ and $y \leftarrow y + \alpha\Delta y$, where the step size $\alpha$ is determined using a backtracking rule. This method converges very quickly and correctly gives me a solution $x$ that minimises my function $f$ and satisfies $Ax=b$, however I am unsure how to enforce $x\geq 0$.

I attempted to use the method given on page 609 of [this](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf/%22boyd%22) book by Boyd. It describes a Newton method to minimise a function $f$ subject to $Ax=b$ and $g(x)<0$. To enforce non-negativity, I set $g(x)=-x$ and, if I worked this out correctly, the Newton step is then:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\nabla^{2}f(x) && -I && A^{T} \\
\mathrm{diag}(\lambda) && \mathrm{diag}(x) && 0 \\
A && 0 && 0 
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
\Delta x \\
\Delta \lambda \\
\Delta y
\end{pmatrix}=-\begin{pmatrix}
\nabla f(x) + A^{T}y - \lambda \\
\lambda x - (1/\alpha)\mathbf{1} \\
Ax - b
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

However, this does not seem to give me the correct solution, and the condition number of the matrix blows up as the iterations progress. Also, the right hand side involves a factor of $1/\alpha$ which also blows up as my step sise $\alpha$ decreases. I am unsure whether I have simply implemented it incorrectly, or computed the matrix incorrectly or if the method is even suitable for my problem at all.

So my question is, is there a simple way to enforce the non-negativity constraint? Am I on the right track?

A lot of the nonlinear optimisation literature that I have looked at seems to discuss either equality or inequality constraints, but not both. The text book I mentioned above does discuss both, but I think it might be more complicated than I require for the simple constraint of $x\geq 0$.

Comment: The book you are referring to discusses exactly what you need(in the same chapter). In my opinion a log-barrier function is probably the most easy way to deal with $-x\leq 0$, i.e. add $-\log(x)$ to the objective.

Comment: @WalterJ Thanks for your response. So should I use the Newton step above (the one without the $\lambda$ variable) and set my objective function equal to $f(x) - \sum \mathrm{log}(x)$? Does this mean that on the right hand side I should replace the $\nabla f(x)$ with $\nabla f(x) - 1/x$, and for the Hessian I should replace $\nabla^{2}f(x)$ with $\nabla^{2}f(x) + \mathrm{diag}(1/x^{2})$.

Comment: I can try to explain it within this comment, but really, the book is great and to the point, so I would advise to check out chapter 11 and if that does not work out come back to this place.

Answer (score 0):

The key issue here is that you want to enforce an inequality constraint $x \geq 0$.  In primal-dual interior point methods, this is typically done by introducing Lagrange multipliers $z_{i}$ for the nonnegativity constraints and then enforcing $x > 0$ and $z > 0$ in the line step by picking $\alpha_{p}$ and $\alpha_{d}$ so that

$x+\alpha_{p} \Delta x > 0$

$z+\alpha_{d} \Delta z > 0$

These conditions further restrict the step length.

In primal-dual interior point methods, a barrier term is also added to the objective function to keep the $x$ and $z$ variables away from 0.